# Probabilty Distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

At a shooting range, a shooter is able to hit a target in either $1$, $2$
 or $3$ shots. Let $X$ be a random variable indicating the number of
 shots fired to hit the target. The following probability function
 was proposed.
     $$f(X) =\frac{X}{6}$$ 
Is this probability function valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(1)=\frac{1}{6}$$
$$f(2)=\frac{2}{6}$$
$$f(3)=\frac{3}{6}$$
they are all between $0$ and $1$, and their sum is $1$. You can conclude